# Correct way to parse this JSON and use it with D3

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps-api-3, d3.js, overlay

I'm using random user generator to get the JSON data:
http://randomuser.me/

I make a call everytime I click a button, so the zip code I get in return I use it to do a geocoder in google maps API and get a latitude and longitude. Until that it has work very well but I don't know how to use it on Google Maps. I'm trying to create D3 circles and there are two ways to do this:

1.- Using the drawing shapes from Google Maps API:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#circles

2.- Using the custom overlay from Google Maps API:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays

I need to do it with the overlay and draw the graphics with D3 like in this example:
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/899711

So my doubts are:

1.- How can I use D3 to use the latitude and longitude and load them? In the example they load JSON from the directory but here I'm using remote data. Should I considered a JSON parse or a String or any other?

2.- What is the correct way to write this as a clean code? And why?

Thank you in advance

index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/d3.v3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v&sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {        
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(16.4706001, -33.6728973),
          zoom:3,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);    
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="map-canvas"></div>

    <div id="button">
      <button id="loadbutton">Click to Load</button>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
var randomuserURL = 'http://api.randomuser.me/';

var myButton = document.getElementById('loadbutton');
myButton.onclick = loadAJAX;

var lat = '';
var lng = '';
var zipcode;
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

function loadAJAX () {
    $.ajax({
      url: randomuserURL,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data){
        zipcode = data.results[0].user.location.zip;
        latlng();
      }
    });
}

function latlng () {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': zipcode}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
             lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
             lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });
    console.log('Latitude: ' + lat + ' Logitude: ' + lng);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically have everything you need.

1. There's no need to load a "local" file -- `d3.json` will take any URL as its first argument. The only problem you may run into are browser security restrictions. In that case [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) may help.
2. If your code works for you, it should be fine. Honestly, you have so little code that it really doesn't matter.